# ViewFactory iphone

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Has anyone successfully used [this](http://pegolon.wordpress.com/2008/11/15/using-uitableviewcell-with-interfacebuilder/) class to load custom tableViewCells. I have tried to create a singleton of the viewFactory class and load the cells using the shared instance but I get the following error...

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '+[ViewFactory sharedMyClassName]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x32a24'

I am using [this](http://projectswithlove.com/projects/SynthesizeSingleton.h.zip) macro to create the singleton, and following the tutorial [here](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html) Anyone had any experience with this before? I realise this may be a longshot but if anyone has ever used it then please let me know.

Many thanks

Jules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason that ViewFactory class is a singleton is so that you can access it globally. It would be trivial to take the bit of code in ViewFactory that does useful work and incorporate it into your own table view controller subclass. That would eliminate the singleton, make it easier to use separate nibs for each table, and (IMO) make your code simpler.

Another approach that works well is to put each type of cell in its own nib and use -loadNibNamed:owner:options: to load the cells as needed. The technique is described in [Loading Custom Table-View Cells From Nib Files](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW20). It's not difficult, and although the example in that section uses only one type of custom cell it's easy to extrapolate to multiple custom cells.

Answer (score 0):

The `define` creates a method called `sharedViewFactory` and not `sharedMyClassName`. It depends on the class name you pass to it. `shared` is prepended to the class name. So all `##classname` will be replaced by `ViewFactory`.

Comment: ah thank you for that...silly mistake on my part although I now have the following error                                             
 Assertion failure in -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1448.89/UITableView.m:5678... I have created a custom UITableViewCell with the id newsTableViewCell and then attempt to load it with                           UITableViewCell * cell = [[ViewFactory sharedViewFactory] cellOfKind:@"newsTableViewCell" forTable:tableView]; Do you have any thoughts on this....many thanks again.

Comment: How did you implement `cellOfKind:forTable:`?

Comment: The first link in my question shows all code that I am using. Apolagies for not posting it here but I am now using my phone to access this site and don't so can't post directly from mac. I amusing that exact code though. Many thanks again.

Comment: I am guessing the cell is not being returned properly in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` but from the looks of it, it all seems ok. Can you post the crash logs? And check if for some reason, `cellOfKind:forTable:` is returning `nil`.

Comment: Deepak I havent forgotten about u... Just working on another part of the app, I'l be back to this soon. Many thanks again